# Never changing public static ip address

Tags: ip-address, static-ip

I need a public IP Address that should never change.

So far I found the following:

- Amazon EC2 Elastic IP Addresses
- Hetzner Failover-IPs can be reassigned to a different Hardware

How sure can I be they never change? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: I'm sure there are better solutions. What's the problem? What is the problem that you are expecting a public IP address that never changes to solve?

Comment: Simple, USE DNS, and don't worry about a fixed IP.

Comment: @Zoredache: Not _that_ simple - what about firewalls and access-lists? But your workflows and documentations should always be prepared for changing IP adresses. At the latest with IPv6... :*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left one option out: Go to your ISP and ask them for a fixed IP address or for a IP range.
Any ISP should be able to do that. Even those who do not list it in obvious places on their web pages.

`How sure can I be they never change?`

Easy. Get your own range. This is how the internet worked for ages.

`Or are there better solutions?`

I think a fixed name is more important than a fixed IP. Which means DNS.
Is there any reason why you need a fixed IP over a fixed name?